# How can I stop my modem from crashing Windows?

Tags: windows, freeze, crash, modem

Sometimes my computer stops responding and crashes when I connect to the Internet via my Huawei EC1261-2 modem. But, when I don't use my PC to connect to the Internet this rarely happens.

Does anyone know what may be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Look for latest drivers on manufacturer website or even try execute a Windows Uptade to try to find another driver automatically.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to update my driver..
if the problem presist i'll tell you again..
thanks for the help friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your modem driver and than reinstalling the modem driver.

Answer (score 0):

As Diogo said, you need to install an updated driver. Your best bet is, in preferable order...

1. From the computer manufacturer's website
2. Windows Update
3. The hardware manufacturer's website